# smallest duration for a beep possible on intel hd audio passed soudncard , c++?

Tags: c++, audio

the only way I know to generate a beep of a desired frequency and duration in C++ using windows API is the [beep function](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms679277(v=vs.85).aspx) but it takes a millisecond passed duration ,is there an alternative that defines a duration on the order of microseconds or less , and does new sound cards based on intel HD audio architecture support such a short beep ?

Comment: What about playing a wav file with the desired frequency and a very short duration?